# Get files and directories affected by commit

Tags: c, libgit2

I want to get list of files and directories affected by specific commit. I have no problem getting the commit itself but I rather don't know how to get affected files and directories.

Just to make it clear I need something like this:
file x - deleted 
file y - added 
file z - modified

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git is snapshot-based; each commit includes a full list of files and their state. Any notion of "affected" files needs another commit to compare it to. This is commonly done against its parents, which seems to be what you're asking about. You can figure out which files are different between two commits (or more exactly, their trees) by using the `git_diff` family of functions.

You can find an example of doing so in the [examples listing](https://libgit2.github.com/docs/guides/101-samples/#diff_commit_to_its_parent) for libgit2. There is also a more general [annotated diff example](https://libgit2.github.com/libgit2/ex/HEAD/diff.html). The second link also shows how to list individual files as well as their contents, if you need that. Check the [reference](https://libgit2.github.com/libgit2/#HEAD/group/diff) for a a full listing of available function to work with diffs.

Note that this won't give you affected directorires by itself, as Git does not track directories, but only files.

Comment: " each commit includes a full list of files and their state." this is what I want.  List of files and their states. Your answer have helped me for thingd I will do later so don't remove the current answer pls. Can you help me which functions does this?  Thanks for comprehensive answer

Comment: @StefanoMtangoo In this very context, this sentence was referring to the file content, mode, ... See the **[Git Parable](http://tom.preston-werner.com/2009/05/19/the-git-parable.html)** for a very simple explanation of the concepts Carlos refers to.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [git diff](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff).

The same function exists in libgit2, and the documentation for it is [here](https://libgit2.github.com/libgit2/#HEAD/type/git_diff).

If you're analyzing older commits, "git diff [commit1] [commitAfterCommit1]" will give you a list of changes that the second commit made from the first. You could prune this output to get yourself just the changed file names.

Comment: No, am not comparing commits. I want to know files changed in this commit.

Comment: You'll find in the reference I gave that you can do a variety of different things, all looking at different data for different commits. If you don't give any arguments it will look at what you have yet to stage for commit yet, for example. I think that's what you're saying you want, but when you say 'files changed in this commit', then you can just do 'git diff [previousCommit] [thisCommit]' to get what was changed in this commit.

Comment: Also can you update the answer to use libgit2 not git command tool